# List to nested list by a field

Tags: dart

I have a list:

```
List<MyObject> list = [MyObject(title: "1a", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "1b", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "2a", genre:"2g"), MyObject(title: "2b", genre:"2g")]
```

I want to convert this list into a nested list so that my nested list view can use the data. I want the convertion to be done by genre field. After the convertion the output should be the following:

```
List<List<MyObject>> newList = [[MyObject(title: "1a", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "1b", genre:"1g")], [MyObject(title: "2a", genre:"2g"), MyObject(title: "2b", genre:"2g")]]
```

Notice:

```
newList[0] == [MyObject(title: "1a", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "1b", genre:"1g")]
newList[1] == [MyObject(title: "2a", genre:"2g"), MyObject(title: "2b", genre:"2g")]
```

is there any short one liners i can use to do this with my list variable? I dont wanna write a long, inefficient code, im new to dart so i could not figure this. Any help would be very cool.

Comment: One way of doing it creating a map indexed by `genere` and then gets its `.values` to get a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add import:

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";
```

then

```
final List<MyObject> list = [MyObject(title: "1a", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "1b", genre:"1g"), MyObject(title: "2a", genre:"2g"), MyObject(title: "2b", genre:"2g")];
final map = groupBy(list, (e) => e.genre);
final finalList = map.values.toList();
```

Comment: i looked for groupBy, thought it was a list extension like in c# but it turns out its not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I suggested from my comment to create Map indexed by genre then get its values.

```dart
class MyObject {
  final String title;
  final String genre;

  MyObject({this.title, this.genre});
  
  String toString() => "{title: ${title}, genre: ${genre}}";
}

List<MyObject> list = [
  MyObject(title: "1a", genre: "1g"),
  MyObject(title: "1b", genre: "1g"),
  MyObject(title: "2a", genre: "2g"),
  MyObject(title: "2b", genre: "2g")
];

void main() {
  var myMap = <String, List<MyObject>>{};

  for (var item in list) {
    if (myMap.containsKey(item.genre) == false) {
      myMap[item.genre] = <MyObject>[item];
    } else {
      myMap[item.genre].add(item);
    }    
  }
  
  print(myMap.values);
}
```

Comment: its always better to write this with a built in function

Comment: @shiv zuh Do you mind sharing what builtin functions we can use in this case? I am new to Dart myself.

Comment: I saw it. I thought all built-in libraries were prefixed with `dart:`. Can you link me to the docs for that library?